# How can I prevent Korge views from updating?

Tags: kotlin, korge

I have an `addFixedUpdater { }` block attached to a view that is being executed on every frame.
Is there a way to pause that block temporarily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

KorGE Views have a chainable `speed` property that acts as a multiplier. By default all the views have that property set to 1.0. If you set to 2.0 your blocks will be executed twice the times, while 0.5 make it to be executed half the times.
In this case, to prevent the addFixedUpdater to be executed for a View subtree, you can just set the `speed` property to 0.0.